# Dismiss a modal view get the parent view resized?

Tags: ios, size, modalviewcontroller, dismiss

I have an issue with presenting/dismissing viewControllers on iOS

Lets say i have an `UIViewController` *A and inside it a add a subview lets say `UIViewController` *mySubview this goes well as i can have N subviews dynamically within my first view...

Then lets say mySubview it's a `UITableVIew` so when user select´s a cell it present another View let´s call it `UIViewController` *C and that goes OK too, the problem is when i want to dismiss C i expected the iPhone to display the A `UIViewController` with de B subview inside it but instead i get the iPhone fully displaying the subview and not the A `UIViewController`

So this is the code that the subview is executing when some cell it´s clicked

```
cuest=[[CuestionarioViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Cuestionario" bundle:nil];
cuest.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;                          [self presentModalViewController:cuest animated:YES];
```

and on the `UIViewController` C this is what dismiss it:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I want to come with a solution not involving resizing the frame again or so.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well maybe if i present the UIViewController *C from the controller *A it would work, but for that i may use a delegate that notify the cell clicked from the subview to the view A

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as i posted on my comments delegations worked like a charm, thanks a lot anyway.